# Axios get request - img src link response format - / are being converted to spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, get, axios

I am trying to generate a dynamic link to a movie poster using an Axios call.

```
function getMovies(searchText){
axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key='+ API_KEY + "&language=en-US&query=" + searchText + "&page=1&include_adult=false")
.then((response) => {
    let movies = response.data.results;
    let output = '';
    $.each(movies, (index, movie) => {
        console.log("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + movie.poster_path);
        let movieUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + movie.poster_path;
        output += `
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="well text-center>
                    <img src="${movieUrl}" >
                    <h5>${movie.title}</h5>
                    <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.imdbID}') target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Movie Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    });
    $('#movies').html(output);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

};

The console.log outputs the correct link syntax, for example: `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//8WmT9i9sili2uLNzGGm3nc7AUR3.jpg`

but on the DOM the link is formatted with spaces instead of / for example:

```
<img src=" http:="" image.tmdb.org="" t="" p="" w185="" 8wmt9i9sili2ulnzggm3nc7aur3.jpg"="">
```

What is going on here?
Do I need to use something like paramsSerializer or encodeURI or is it something else?

Comment: try to concat template string, may not be pretty but it might do the trick.

    output += `<div class="col-md-3">
                         <div class="well text-center>
                         <img src='` + movieUrl + `' />
                         `<h5>${movie.title}</h5>
                           <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.imdbID}') target="_blank"  class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Movie Details</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` attribute value for the `div` below wasn't closed with a double quote.

```
<div class="well text-center>
```

The browser could only try to make sense of it and it treats every character until the next `"` in `img src="` as a value of the `class` attribute for the `div`.

Then, the value of `movieUrl` is treated as attribute values as well *not without it properly escaped*.

**Closing the missing quotes (`<div class="well text-center">`) should resolve that issue**.

Comment: Thanks Oluwafemi! Great catch, that was the problem. Just one little ". Thanks for the great explanation too.